# I make simple chat using python flask and html/css/js but after adding new messages to database they don't appear on page

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, web

I have attempted different approaches to solve the problem, but new messages still do not appear. I would prefer not to use AJAX or Flask-Socket. I also make the page reload every second with JS, but using this method, navigating the page is impossible. I also tried to call some JS functions, but it didn't work either.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from data import add_message, read_messages, create_table

create_table()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Retrieve messages from the database
    messages = read_messages()
    message_history = [row[1] for row in messages]

    return render_template('index.html', message_history=message_history)

@app.route('/send_message', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    message = request.form['message']
    print(f"Received message: {message}")

    # Store the message in the database
    add_message(message)

    return jsonify({'status': 'success'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run the app on the local network, accessible from other devices
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

data.py this code work with database

```
import sqlite3

database = 'data.db'

def create_table():
    # Connect to SQLite database (or create it if it doesn't exist)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database)

    # Create a cursor object to interact with the database
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Create a table if it doesn't exist
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            text TEXT NOT NULL
        )
    ''')

    # Commit the changes to the database
    conn.commit()

    # Close the cursor (table created, no need for it)
    cursor.close()


def add_message(text):
    # Connect to SQLite database (or create it if it doesn't exist)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database)

    # Create a cursor object to interact with the database
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Insert data into the table
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO messages (text) VALUES (?)", (text,))

    # Commit the changes to the database
    conn.commit()

    # Close the cursor (data added, no need for it)
    cursor.close()


def read_messages():
    # Connect to SQLite database (or create it if it doesn't exist)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database)

    # Create a cursor object to interact with the database
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Query the data
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM messages")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # Close the cursor (data read, no need for it)
    cursor.close()

    return rows
```

index.html main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chat</title>
    <style>
         body {
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #272727;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .chat-container {
            max-width: 400px;
            width: 100%;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            border-radius: 8px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #2c2c2c;
        }

        .chat {
            padding: 10px;
            max-height: 300px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            background-color: #2c2c2c;
        }

        .input-container {
            display: flex;
            background-color: #474747;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #f0c419;
        }

        #message-input {
            flex: 1;
            padding: 8px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #474747;
            border: 1px solid #f0c419;
            color: #fff;
        }

        button {
            margin-left: 10px;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #f0c419;
            color: #272727;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #chat-list {
            padding: 10px;
            max-height: 300px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            background-color: #2c2c2c;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chat-container">
        <ul id="chat-list">
            {% for message in message_history %}
                <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div class="input-container">
            <input type="text" id="message-input" placeholder="Type your message..." onkeydown="handleKeyDown(event)">
            <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function sendMessage() {
            var messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
            var messageText = messageInput.value.trim();
    
            if (messageText !== '') {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "/send_message", true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                        console.log("Server response:", xhr.responseText);
                        
                        // Update chat box with the received message
                        updateChatBox(messageText);
                    }
                };
    
                xhr.send("message=" + encodeURIComponent(messageText));
    
                // Clear the input field
                messageInput.value = '';
            }
        }
    
        function updateChatBox(message) {
            var chatList = document.getElementById('chat-list');
            var newMessage = document.createElement('li');
            newMessage.textContent = message;
            chatList.appendChild(newMessage);
    
            // Scroll to the bottom of the chat box to show the latest message
            chatList.scrollTop = chatList.scrollHeight;
        }
    
        function handleKeyDown(event) {
            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                event.preventDefault();
                sendMessage();
            }
        }
        function fetchAndUpdateMessages() {
        var chatList = document.getElementById('chat-list');

        fetch('/get_messages')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(messages => {
                // Clear existing messages
                chatList.innerHTML = '';

                // Update chat list with the received messages
                messages.forEach(message => {
                    var newMessage = document.createElement('li');
                    newMessage.textContent = message;
                    chatList.appendChild(newMessage);
                });

                // Scroll to the bottom of the updated chat list
                chatList.scrollTop = chatList.scrollHeight;
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching messages:', error));
    }

    // Call fetchAndUpdateMessages when the page loads
    window.onload = function () {
        fetchAndUpdateMessages();
    };

    // Set an interval to regularly update the messages
    setInterval(fetchAndUpdateMessages, 500); // Update every 5 seconds (adjust as needed)
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really don't want to make a chatsystem that relies on long- or short polling techniques like Ajax. Especially not one that relies on querying the database to read the messages. The amount of queries that your system will have to process each second will stack up so fast that your chat is going to have resource issues with just 10 users online at the same time. You should definitely look into websockets instead and utilize those.

Comment: Your example code works. The only thing missing is the `/get_messages` route regularly called by fetch.